# How to pre-populate dot files for active directory users on RHEL

Tags: linux, bash, active-directory, redhat-enterprise-linux

So I'm running into an interesting issue, I can't seem to find any good documentation on how to effectively go about this.

I have a RHEL box connected to AD and want bootstrap each user profile so vim and a few other bash aliases are ready to go upon login.

What's the best way to go about this? I know you can modify /etc/bashrc,/etc/bashprofile, which are then copied over to the user profile. I just feel like there is a better way of going about this.

Answer (score 2):

Script files within `/etc/profile.d` are sourced by the user's shell upon login.